# Multi-Line String to an Array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a list (as a string, say $peoplelist) like this:

```
Name1
Name2
Name3
```

What I'm trying to do is separate that entire string into separate elements (where each line corresponds to a new element // i.e. Element 1 is "Name1", Element 2 is "Name2", etc.) and place them into an array (essentially, use lines breaks as delimiters and split that string into separate elements to be put into an array under unique indexes).

This is what I have so far:

```
# Step 1 - Fetch the list
$peoplelist = file_get_contents('http://domain.tld/file-path/')
//The Contents of $peoplelist is stated at the top of this question.
//(The list of names in blue)

# Step 2 - Split the List, and put into an array
$arrayX = preg_split("/[\r\n]+/", $playerlist);
var_dump($arrayX);
```

Now, using the code mentioned above, this is what I get (output):

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(71) "Name1
Name2
Name3
" }
```

According to my output, (from what I understand) the entire string (the list from Step 1) is being placed into an array under a single index, which means that the second step isn't effectively doing what I intend it to do.

My question is, how do I split the list into separate elements (where each separate line on the original list is a unique element) and place these elements in an array?

**EDIT:** **Thanks for all the help, everyone! And thank you, localheinz, for the solution :)**

**NOTE:** If anyone reads this in the future, please ensure that your source file for the list contains raw data - my mistake was using a file with .php extension that contained html tags - this html script interfered with the indexing process.

Comment: `"/\r\n|\n|\r/"` should be `"/[\r\n]+/"`

Comment: Thanks for the correction Lashane :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `file()`:

```
$arrayX = file(
    'http://domain.tld/file-path/',
    FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES
);
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: this is the best of the answers (so far)

Comment: Thanks for the answer localheinz - I'll try it out, and let you know how it goes

Comment: It doesn't appear to work for me localheinz - the output displays an empty array.

Comment: Weird, can you provide more details?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, localheinz - well, it displayed an empty array - none of the data was added into the array. Do you know why? I'll try again, and reply with more information. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hey localheinz. This is the output I get: `array(11) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) ""
  [1]=>
  string(6) ""
  [2]=>
  string(33) ""
  [3]=>
  string(7) ""
  [4]=>
  string(6) ""
  [5]=>
  string(0) ""
  [6]=>
  string(41) " "
  [7]=>
  string(0) ""
  [8]=>
  string(29) “Name1
Name2
"
  [9]=>
  string(7) ""
  [10]=>
  string(7) ""
}
` Thanks for that example, localheinz - I'll try to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I think it may be due to an issue with my source file not being formatted correctly.

Comment: I think I've figured it out. I viewed the page source of the php file, and found this: 

`array(11) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "<html>"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "<head>"
  [2]=>
  string(33) "<title>Online Name List</title>"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "</head>"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "<body>"
  [5]=>
  string(0) ""
  [6]=>
  string(41) "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15"> "
  [7]=>
  string(0) ""
  [8]=>
  string(25) "Name1<br>Name2<br>"
  [9]=>
  string(7) "</body>"
  [10]=>
  string(7) "</html>"
}`

My source file (for the list) is a .php file that contains some html script, which is probably the issue.

Comment: It looks like html from my .php source file is interfering with the indexing process. Is there a way i can get this php "list" into a raw format with only line breaks? (like, .txt, xml or json) Thanks in advance, localheinz :) I'm sure this method will work once I fix the source file.

Comment: Alright, got the data into a raw .txt file. Current list: `Name1<br>Name2<br>`. Will try your script again (not sure if it works for the <br> tag - if not, I'll try using explode with <br> as a delimiter. Thanks :) Will keep you updated!

Comment: Yes! That worked. 
Output: 
`array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Name1"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "Name2"
}`
Thanks so much for your help localheinz, and thank you everyone else for your answers, I appreciate it! I've learnt a lot today. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) in PHP. See this code below splitting strings using delimeter `\n`:

```
explode("\n", $string);
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but for windows the line break delimiter is `\r\n` for some particular cases.

Comment: delimeter is not a problem

Comment: Hey Ceeee - thanks for the answer, but that doesn't appear to work for me. I get the same output

Answer (score 3):

Try it.

```
<?php

$peoplelist = file_get_contents('text.txt');
$arrayX[0] = $peoplelist;
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($arrayX);

?>
```

=> OUTPUT

```
  array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "Name1
   Name2
   Name3"
 }
```

Comment: Hey Mukesh, thank you for replying. This script added all the names under a single index - is there a way to separate so that [0]=> Name1, [1]=> Name2, etc.?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding something... if I am, please let me know! I'm assuming that [0], [1] and any number within a set of brackets refers to a index number... am I correct? Also, what does string(int) mean? Thanks again :)

Comment: Just figured out that the integer refers to the number of characters within the entry. It looks like html from my .php source file is interfering with the indexing process. Do you know a way to output the list into a raw format with only line breaks? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with a delimiter [PHP_EOL](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#116600) for cross platform.

```
$str = "Name1
Name2
Name3";

var_dump(explode(PHP_EOL,$str));
```

will result to

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Name1"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Name2"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "Name3"
}
```

Comment: Be aware PHP_EOL is good for the server side, not to handle user input.
It might work for him, might not.

Comment: Hey roullie - thanks for the answer. However, when I tried it, it didn't appear to work. Output: array(1) { [0]=> string(52) "Name1 Name2 Name3 " }